# template id="1921" from inside editor doesnt work?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have inherited management of a WordPress based site. 
And suddenly something like this `[template id="1921"]` typed in the editor isn't working.

Been looking in the DB and there are posts with a `post_type` template. But I can't find any plugin or documentation to get these bracket template calls to work again. All I can find is PHP options, but I would rather just fix whatever used to work.

EDIT: Isn't `[display-posts id="x"]` suppose to be an official WP shortcode? All it displays on the site where content of post with id x is suppose to be is "[display-posts id="x"]". Why would it do that?

Comment: this is  a shortcode [template id="1921"] of template please check php file

Comment: which theme you are use?

Comment: pivot, not sure what you mean with check php file

Comment: without function not create shortcode

Comment: `[template]` isn't a standard WordPress shortcode. Maybe you used a plugin or theme on previous sites that had a shortcode like that, but it doesn't mean it's going to work on any site.

Comment: @JacobPeattie ok, never used this before. it is on a site I didn't do. It used to work, it isn't now. What can I do to figure out how to get it working?